# Supply data frame as input to multivariate function

Tags: r, mapply

I've seen some similar answers but nothing that actually does what I'm trying to do. I have a function with many inputs, and I would like to be able to give the function a dataframe with columns named for the inputs. Example below

```
my.fun <- function(alpha,beta,gamma,delta){
    phi = (alpha + beta*gamma)/delta
    return(phi)
  }
my.df <- data.frame(alpha = 3, beta = 4, gamma= 0.5, delta = 11)
my.fun(my.df)
```

I want my.fun to assign values to each variable according to the matching column name. Another answer suggested

```
mapply(my.fun,my.df[,1],my.df[,2]... etc.)
```

but my real case has a lot more than 4 variables and it gets tedious fast. Can you get mapply to just read the column names instead of putting in each individual entry explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
do.call("my.fun", my.df)
```

to expand your data.frame columns into function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the function to take a data frame as an input.

```
my.fun <- function(df){
    with(df, (alpha + beta*gamma)/delta)
}

my.fun(my.df)
[1] 0.4545455
```

Comment: (alpha + beta*gamma)/delta is just a dummy example, the real my.fun is 60 lines
I'd also want people to be able to put in individual inputs if they want to